# Public IP address of local network machines?

Tags: networking, ip

I have a home local network with two machines connected to router:

- Linux Ubuntu x86_64
- Linux Ubuntu Arm aarch64 (headless, no GUI)

I tried `ip r` to find out the public IP of both machines. This works for the first machine, gives `123.456.789.123 via 192.168.5.1` . But when I log into Arm machine from x86_64 machine, the same `ip r` command just gives local IP: `192.168.5.163`.

Does the 2nd machine have public IP, and how to I find it?

Comment: Are the machines connected directly to WAN, or behind a router? In the latter case, you will need to use an external service (ex. `curl ipv4.icanhazip.com`)

Comment: Connected via a router.

Comment: ``dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com -4``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither machine has a public IP address.

Your router has a public IP address, and you can choose to configure Port Forwarding on the router to send traffic for that public IP address and port on to a device on your internal network.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a standard home setup.

You can get the IP addresses of your linuces with:

```
ip addr
```

This will give you a list of IP addresses that are assigned to the different interfaces on your systems. They will all be in the private range (192.168.5.xx).

Your router will do a NAT translation from those private-space addresses to the one public IP address that you have. Somewhere in the GUI or CLI access of the router, you can get IP addresses of the router too (varies rom one router to another how to do this). You will see that the router has a 192.168.5.1 on one interface (where your Linux systems are connected) and 123.456.789.123 on another interface, where your provider is connected.

Your `ip r` gives the routing table, not the addresses on the system. You will see something like

```
default via 192.168.5.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

which means that your outgoing router is defined as the default gateway.